Migrate simple language from Camel 3.20 to 4.0
I'm trying to migrate my Camel application from version 3.20 to 4.0 and I'm facing issues with updating the $simple{headers.CustomFileName} configuration. Currently, in my Application.properties file I have the following setup:
Application.properties
internal.out.uri=file:///integration/out\
?tempFileName=$simple{headers.CustomFileName}.tmp\
&fileName=$simple{headers.CustomFileName}\
&fileExist=Fail\
&autoCreate=false

It seems that with Camel 4, I need to use the simple language differently. I tried to replace it with &fileName=${headers.CustomFileName}\, but I'm getting an error stating that the placeholder is not resolved.
How do I correctly update the configuration for Camel 4.0 using simple language?
